# Deleting an element from an array in an active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an object that looks like this

```
tv_info _id: 237827483784783, channels: [:a, :b, :c]
```

How would I delete just `:b` from channels so it would look like

```
tv_info _id: 237827483784783, channels: [:a, :c]
```

I've only found an update method but no delete method. For 
example

```
tv_info.update(channels: :a)
```

Would change it to

```
tv_info _id: 237827483784783, channels: [:a]
```

but i need to keep the `:c`

I'm looking for something like

```
tv_info.delete(channels: :b)
```

Comment: That does not look like a valid literal expression of any object, at least. What kind of object is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `:b` by using:

```
tv_info[:channels].delete(:b)
```

Hope it helps :D

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same as in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything like

```
new_channles = tv_info.channels.select { |c| c != :b }
tv_info.update(channels: new_channels)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Just access the array stored under channels directly:

```
tv_info.tap { |hash| hash[:channels].delete(:b) }
```

This uses :

- [`tap`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/tap) to ensure the entire modified hash is returned
- [`delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-delete) to remove the matching elements from the array.

Hope that helps, let me know if you have any questions or issues.